# React with MVC and Sitecore 9

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, sitecore

I currently have a Sitecore 8.2 site using Helix which we are upgrading to 9 in a couple months. I was wondering if Sitecore 9 allows for both React and MVC views to work simultaneously and if it is worth the effort. My current dilemma is I would like my frontend developer to be concentrating on the ui and not having to master sitecore. Hoewever, my current site is all MVC and Helix and I need it to coexist. In my perfect world, I would like to be able to maintain the MVC views (used for layouts and components) and create new modules in React.

Comment: This is very broad question. If you're goal is to have a complete SPA based in something like React/Vue/Angular running, you would mostly use Sitecore an API to fetch data for React/Vue/Angular to render views/templates. Otherwise you run the risk of re-bootstrapping/re-mounting React/Vue/Angular on every single page when using Sitecore's default Postback server-side rendered pages. You really need to consider what your gaining turning a Helix or whatever component, like a panel or button, into a React version of it and justifying re-mounting react each time potentially.

Comment: At minimum, you should consider posting a specific example of how you are currently using React with Helix and the issues you are encountering.

Comment: Your two choices are Sitecore.React, https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2016/07/23/Sitecore-and-React-It-IS-that-easy/. And moving to JSS which is released in 9.1. I use Sitecore quite a lot for my Sitecore work.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAuer. This is what I was looking for!